# Htaccess issue with default page

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a dynamic page that links are `?p=home` so for example mysite.com/?p=home
Although with this, every page worked but the default home when you enter the site.

I then added: `DirectoryIndex index.php?p=home` to make it take me to the ?p=home by default, instead of going to index.php [which had no page on it]. But now my home works but all the rest of the pages don't.

Comment: Post your complete .htaccess code.

Comment: I did. "DirectoryIndex index.php?p=home"

Comment: Make it `DirectoryIndex index.php` and open this URL: `http://site.com?p=home` see if that works.

Comment: @anubhava It works, even without that [I pasted abit of my php code that makes this happen below in another comment] but what im aiming for is for when you go to http://site.com it will automaticly take you to ?p=home without it interfering with the rest [like it is doing]

Comment: ok posted an answer below, try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?p=home [L]
```